# How to write to a csv file through ftp in rails 3?

Tags: ruby, csv, ftp, libraries

I am trying to write to a csv file through ftp. Here is what i have so far:

```
require 'net/ftp'
require 'csv'

users = User.users.limit(5)

csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["email_addr", "first_name", "last_name"]

  users.each do |user|
    new_line = [user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name]
    csv << new_line
  end
end

csv_file = CSV.new(csv_string)

ftp = Net::FTP.new('**SERVER NAME**')
ftp.login(user = "**USERNAME**", passwd = "**PASSWORD**")
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + 'my_file.csv', csv_file)
ftp.quit()
```

I get the error "wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)". When i change the line to ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + 'my_file.csv', csv_file, 1024) it says "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)". I've also tried using storlines instead, but that gave me errors also. Does anybody have any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: woops my bad. i thought you were getting them from the ENV.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + 'my_file.csv', csv_file)
```

csv_file needs to be an actual File object, not another kind of object.

### > (from ruby core)

storbinary(cmd, file, blocksize, rest_offset = nil) { |data| ... }

---

Puts the connection into binary (image) mode, issues the given server-side
command (such as "STOR myfile"), and sends the contents of the file named file
to the server. If the optional block is given, it also passes it the data, in
chunks of blocksize characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'net/ftp'
```

## Login to the FTP server

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.sample.com', 'test', 'pass')
```

## OR

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.sample.com')
ftp.login('test', 'pass')
```

## Switch to the desired directory

```
ftp.chdir('source/files')
```

## Get the file we need and save it to our 'ftp_photos' directory

```
ftp.getbinaryfile('photos_2009-03-29.zip', 'ftp_photos/photos.zip')
```

## We're done, so we need to close the connection

```
ftp.close
```

http://travisonrails.com/2009/03/29/ruby-net-ftp-tutorial

This will help you.