# How to upload the csv file to ftp server in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I write a function to export the csv data, but i don't know how to request the export url to upload the csv file to ftp server in ruby ?
Who can tell me how to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701896/how-to-write-to-a-csv-file-through-ftp-in-rails-3

Answer (score 8):

You can use net/ftp to solve this problem.

```
require 'net/ftp'
require 'open-uri'
Net::FTP.open('SERVER_Name', 'USER', 'Password') do |ftp|
  ftp.passive = true
  ftp.putbinaryfile("Your.csv")
end
```

Comment: but how to request the export url automatically?

Comment: You can put this code on a method. if u call the method it will work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It Worked for me you can also try this:

```
require 'net/ftp'

path = "tmp/" 
filename = 'product.csv'
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.*****.io') 
ftp.login(user = "****", passwd = "******") 
ftp.putbinaryfile(path + filename, filename) 
ftp.quit()
```